# Redirecting to different page using hashed password dont work

Tags: php

I have this hashing of password with my php code. I want to redirect users to edit_password.php if they are new users. I made them a default account with their username and the default password is admin. the password is my basis to redirect. But I am confused on how to make it with my code, kindly check my code, thanks. 
Here's my code:

```
<?php 

    require("common.php"); 

    $submitted_username = ''; 

    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                id, 
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        "; 

        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        $login_ok = false; 

        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row) 
        { 
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
            for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
            { 
                $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
            } 

        if($check_password === $row['password']) // <---- i want to insert some code here like if($check_password === $row['password'] || 'admin') to redirect new users. but i dont know how to.
            { 
                $login_ok = true; 
            } 
          if($login_ok) 
        { 
            unset($row['salt']); 
            unset($row['password']); 

            $_SESSION['user'] = $row; 

            header("Location: index.php"); 
            die("Redirecting to: index.php"); 

        } 
        else 
        { 
            echo("<font color=red>Login Failed.</font>"); 

            $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
        } 
        }
    }

?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider removing that hashing. Read the PHP Password FAQ first: http://php.net/faq.passwords - Also I must admit I have real problems to understand your question, I can not bring together what you write in text and what you write in code.

Comment: WHy are you placing even `die('message')` after `header()`? You should use exist(); because one the browser send HTTP header it, won't display any outputs.

Comment: @TheCOMPLETEPHPNewbie: *Wrong*. The browser displays all outputs if you want to, even for redirects. Set per HTTP specs.

Comment: How is that? @hakre normally, if I call `header('Location: page');` then It will instantly take me to that page, ignoring everything below that! Are you sure?

Comment: i'm sorry but what i want is to direct new users to a different page which they can edit their password for them to protect their account, but in my code i don't know how to add the code or what code should i add to complete what i want. thanks

Comment: @TheCOMPLETEPHPNewbie: Check the documentation of your browser where you can disable automatic redirects. Then surf the web and you might view it with completely different eyes.

Comment: Who in God's name spoke about disabling automatic redirects? @hakre 
The user simply needed to redirect after successful login. And, there is no way if  `header();` is initiated, that you can display anything after that. I am saying this bearing in mind, there is nothing modified in the PHP.ini if that is where automatic redirects is displayed.

Comment: @ROYFinley do you think, it makes sense to display a die('message'); after `header()` is called? doesn't header automatically redirect, disregarding anything after it??

Comment: I never use it, but I have combined them and used it. die(header())

Comment: Yea, because there is no use for it. But, @hakre thinks otherwise.

Comment: actually if you cant connect to index.php and you tried to refresh the page, then "redirecting to: index.php will be displayed on the browser. that's why i use that than having nothing displayed on the browser.

Comment: But if you can't connect to index.php, then showing "redirecting" message would be in accurate to the browser. I think, the exit(); would work better, possibly if you have other codes below the header(); that should not be executed.

Comment: @TheCOMPLETEPHPNewbie: Just saying your assumptions do not make any difference technically. The output is send to the browser with the redirect. Also giving a response body with the redirect is good practice. That's just all.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't believe the browser sends output after header. There is also no way to prove it

Answer (score 1):

```
if($login_ok) 
        { 
            unset($row['salt']); 
            unset($row['password']); 


            $_SESSION['user'] = $row; 
        if($_POST['password'] === "admin")
            {
                header(""); 
            }
            else
                {
                    header("Location: index.php"); 
                    die("Redirecting to: index.php"); 
                }
        }
```

A simple condition check once you have verified the user should do the trick.

Comment: if you use an account with different password you can not connect to index anymore because you are not registered on the session.

Comment: not sure what you mean. the session is set before we test the condition of the password. the condition test should not effect the session

Comment: i test your code. users with admin passwords are directed to my edit_account.php page, but when i log out and try other users, users with different password cannot connect anymore.

Comment: Are you destroying your session on logout.

Comment: i edit if($check_password === $row['password']) and changed to if($check_password === $row['password'] && 'admin') but same things happen the users with admin password and the users with different password are directed to the header. my point is to manage the users that are registered to DB and has a password of 'admin' to be directed to my edit_account for them to change their password. can you help me to do that, thanks.

Comment: shold be if($check_password === $row['password'] && $row['password'] === 'admin')

Comment: its not working too. anyway, thanks again, but if you manage to work on it, and help me i appreciate it a lot.